# sorting matrix rows preserving column names for each row in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix X with column names

```
names(X) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
a b c d 
1 2 3 4 
2 7 1 5
```

I need to sort each row and preserve the column names, so that each row in the sorted matrix has has individual column names:

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4


c a d b
1 2 5 7
```

I tried the to assign names to each row:

```
for(i in 1:2) { 
  X[i,] <- sort(X[i,]) 
  names(X[i,]) <- names(sort(X[i,])) 
}
```

but still have the original column names.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = lapply(1:NROW(X), function(i) X[i, order(X[i,]), drop = FALSE])
mylist
#[[1]]
#     a b c d
#[1,] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#     c a d b
#[1,] 1 2 5 7
```

**DATA**

```
X = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L),
              .Dim = c(2L, 4L),
              .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b", "c", "d")))
```

Comment: While using this snippet, I get <b/> > x[[1]][1] <b/> How to access its name 'a'?

Comment: sorry, I need to know the name of the 1st element.

Comment: > x[[1]][,1]
Error in x[[1]][, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: > names(x[1,1])
[1] "a"

Comment: yes; I did it yesterday but didn't format my last comment properly. thx!